# Python class that allows for lazy API calls and two types of construction

Tags: python, api, module, python-3.6

I've been working on a project to create a python module for an existing REST API. Basically the API consists in fetching data about official geographic locations in Brazil.

For simplification reasons, suppose we have the classes: `Regions` and `Region`. `Regions` is responsible for collecting all country regions from the API and producing a list of `Region` objects. The user should be able to use both classes to fetch information. Now I have a few questions about this:

1. If the user wants to use `Region` directly to create an object for a specific region of the country, how should I limit the creation of the object to allow only existing regions, avoiding an object representing a region that does not exist? Should I consult the API everytime to check if the region exists? I should only allow a `Region` with id 1 to 5.
2. I would like to make lazy API calls. That is, the call is only going to happen if it has never happened before in that execution. Is this the best approach (below)? (Don't know if that's the definition of lazy, but the goal here is to minimize calls).
3. When I create a `Region` object from inside the `Regions` class, I already have all the information I need to create each `Region`. But if the user instatiates `Region` directly, I haven't made any calls yet. How should I build the Region class to allow for these two approaches? I don't want to call the API again when creating the `Region` object from inside the `Regions` class.

The simplfiied code is provided below:

```py
class Region():
    def __init__(self, id_=None, code=None, name=None):
        self.id = id_
        self.code = code
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Region(id_={self.id}, name=\"{self.name}\", code=\"{self.code}\")"


class Regions():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__ran_once = False
        self.result = None
        self.content = None
        self.json = None

    def __get(self):
        self.json = HttpClient.get("regioes")

        self.content = []
        for obj in self.json:
            self.content.append(
                Region(obj["id"], obj["sigla"], obj["nome"])
            )

    def all(self, format_json=False):
        if not self.__ran_once:
            self.__get()
            self.__ran_once = True

        if format_json:
            return self.json

        return self.content

    def names(self):
        if not self.__ran_once:
            self.__get()
            self.__ran_once = True

        return [r.name for r in self.content]
```

Comment: What version(s) of Python do you need to support?

Comment: @AlexHall 3.6 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would discourage the user from instantiating `Region` directly. If they do so, it's at their own risk. You can put that in the docstring.

What you are describing is caching, not laziness. I would write the Regions class like this:

```py
from cached_property import cached_property


class Regions:
    @cached_property
    def json(self):
        return HttpClient.get("regioes")

    @cached_property
    def content(self):
        return [
            Region(obj["id"], obj["sigla"], obj["nome"])
            for obj in self.json
        ]

    @cached_property
    def names(self):
        return [r["name"] for r in self.json]
```

Install [`cached_property`](https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property) with `pip install cached-property`.

Comment: But `content` will fail if I haven't called `json` yet, right?

Comment: @GustavoEfeiche you misunderstand, `json` is now a property, it is called and set on demand. You no longer have to manage it yourself.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, I really didn't know about the cached_property decorator. Thank you for the reply. I've also decided not to encourage the use of the Region class as you said